# Update from Logstash to Elastic Search failed

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to parse a simple logfile with logstash and post the results to elastic search. I've configured logstash according to the [log stash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html).

But Logstash reports this error:

```
Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["http://localhost:9200/"]',
but Elasticsearch appears to be unreachable or down!
{:client_config=>{:hosts=>["http://localhost:9200/"], :ssl=>nil,
:transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil,
:ssl=>{}}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore,
:logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false,
:reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false}, :error_message=>"Connection refused",
:level=>:error}
```

My configuration looks like this:

```
input { stdin{} }

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{NOTSPACE:demo}"}
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => "localhost:9200"}
}
```

Of course elastic search is available when calling http://localhost:9200/

Versions: logstash-2.0.0, elasticsearch-2.0.0
OSX

I've found a [thread](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/103) with a similar issue. But this seems to be a bug in an older logstash version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1

This works:

```
output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"}
}
```